# Is there a way to link to a specific line of an arbitrary sha1 and file on GitHub?

Tags: github

For example, I can link to a specific **line** of an arbitrary tag and **file**, [like this](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.8/railties/lib/initializer.rb#L40).

And I can link to an arbitrary **sha1** and **file**, [like this](http://github.com/rails/rails/raw/60122e81a3504ed171a761573ed16cb034c79c13/railties/lib/initializer.rb), but that's the raw file, so no way to link to a line there.

Is there a way to do **sha1**, **file** and **line** at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took your original hash link, changed `raw` in URL to `blob`, added `#L40`, and got [this](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/60122e81a3504ed171a761573ed16cb034c79c13/railties/lib/initializer.rb#L40). Is this the thing you wanted?

Comment: Exactly the solution I was going to suggest.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I wanted. Thanks! :) (just wish they would also show a yellow fadeout on the line selected...)

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** No

**Long Answer**

Line links are achieved by anchor links. After parsing the HTML document, you browser has the knowledge of these anchors and can position the top line of your view frame to requested anchor.

```
http://github.com/.../initializer.rb#L40
```

In this example, anchor is named `L40`.

On the other hand, raw files are text files and GitHub sends them as is with `Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8` header. Response content is displayed as is and there is no possibility to direct browser to a predefined offset.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I didn't mean if I could link to a line in the raw text file itself. The question was rather if there was a way to form a URL with sha1, file, and anchor to the appropriate line.